# How to override @GeneratedValue in a sub class

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

If I have only GeneratedValue in super class and if I have a specific generator type in subclass, how can i override this feature.

SUPER CLASS :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
```

SUB CLASS:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "a", sequenceName = "a")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "a")
private Long id;
```

Comment: Check if this post can help you,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass

Comment: Super class is untouchable. What i like to do is override the @GeneratedValue for anything that i like. Not only sequence.