# MappedSuperclass - Change SequenceGenerator in Subclass without @GeneratedValue on the Superclass

Tags: java, hibernate, sequence, mappedsuperclass, sequence-generators

I have a base class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class SuperClass{
    @Id
    protected Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

The @GeneratedValue is not used since the id is generated using a BackendSession

**There are a lot of inheritance from this class so one can't change it!**

my sub class:
I tried to override the getId method

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FTC_DATA")
@SequenceGenerator(name="sequence", sequenceName = "FTC_DATA_SEQ")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

    @Override
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "FTC_DATA_SEQ")
    public void getId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

But I fail on IdentifierGenerationException, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass

Comment: I tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8589928/mappedsuperclass-change-sequencegenerator-in-subclass - but it is with changing the super class to have GeneratedValue.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me. Remove getId() from SuperClass, remove the @Override from SubClass getId() and move the @Id annotation to the SubClass getId().

Comment: It may solve the problem.However, if the id is used in other subclasses, by removing it from the superclass you break all other subclasses.

Comment: I have a total of 6 subclasses and this is not a problem.

Comment: Just to clarify. The ID attribute is not removed, just the getter.

Comment: Ah, OK. Should it work to move the @Id to the method in the super class?

Comment: I have @Id in the subclasses. If I remember correctly it didn't work when it was in the superclass.