# Hibernate annotation mapping for java extended classes

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am working on a Spring Hibernate project where I have three classes 
`BaseEntity`, `Person` & `Owner`.

`Person` extends `BaseEntity`, `Owner` extends `Person`.

### BaseEntity.java

```
public class BaseEntity {

    private Integer id;

        Getters & Setters
```

### Person.java

```
public class Person extends BaseEntity {

    private String firstName;

    private String lastName;

       Getters & Setters
```

### Owner.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="OWNERS")
public class Owner extends Person {

    @Column(name="ADDRESS")
    private String address;

    @Column(name="CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name="TELEPHONE")
    private String telephone;

    Getter and Setters
```

Now I want to map all the properties of the three classes in a single table which
is `Owner`. Can anyone please help me how do I map?

I have a xml based mapping for this & I want to do it in annotation

```
<class name="org.springframework.samples.petclinic.Owner" table="owners">
        <id name="id" column="id">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>
        <property name="firstName" column="first_name"/>
        <property name="lastName" column="last_name"/>
        <property name="address" column="address"/>
        <property name="city" column="city"/>
        <property name="telephone" column="telephone"/>
    </class>
```

I thought of using table per class inheritance mapping but here in xml I see no 
discriminator column being used.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Concrete class as a mapped superclass

Use [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation.

> > JPA (...) defines a mapped superclass concept defined though the [@MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation or the  element. A mapped superclass is not a persistent class, but allow common mappings to be define for its subclasses.

More: [Java Persistence/Inheritance](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Inheritance)

### Example

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseEntity {
    ...
}

@MappedSuperclass
public class Person extends BaseEntity {
   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="OWNERS")
public class Owner extends Person {
    ...
}
```

Look also at this question: [Hibernate : How override an attribute from mapped super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class?rq=1)