# Hibernate Mapping best practice

Tags: java, hibernate

I am wondering if there are any special solutions or software design patterns for the following scenario.
I have similar attributes for my Hibernate-Mapping-Classes, like isEnabled, isDetelable, dateCreated, lastModified, ... . I don't want to repeat the property definition in each class, instead define them once, and add the property to the classes I want. For example ClassA can have isEnabled and dateCreated, ClassB can have dateCreated and isDeletable, ClassC can have isEnabled, isDetelable, lastModified and so on.

Comment: Possibly related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class

Comment: Searching hibernate inheritance gives proper answers for this... Solution: `@MappedSuperClass`.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Hibernate - it is a classic software design question. And all possible solutions are supported by Hibernate: Composition, Aggregation and Inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the `@MappedSuperclass` annotation to create a superclass for your entities which contains the fields you want. Another solution is to use an `@Embeddable` class that contains the fields and use the `@Embedded` annotation to add them to only specific entities, in which case you don't need to extend a super entity.