# @MappedSuperclass and implementation table

Tags: java, jpa, inheritance, mappedsuperclass

I inherited some pretty awful code that I am looking to refactor to make more reusable.  There is a set of reporting tables which are primarily composed of 3 columns: `id`, `report_type_fk`, and `report_description`.  I would like to merge all the reporting tables into one for ease of use.

I am refactoring the code and think that it would be better to break our current entities up so that `Report` is an abstract class with `type` implementations.  For example a `DmvReport extends Report`, `CreditScoreReport extends Report`, etc.

The problem I am running into is that there would only be 1 report table that all entities would need to save to.  Is there a way to make all concrete implementations of the `abstract Report` object save into the same table?

Here's an example of the bad code I inherited

Report class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class Report<E extends Exception> {
    private long id;
    private ReportType type;
    private String description;
   ...
   ...
}
```

CreditReport class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "credit_report")
public class CreditScore Report<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {
    private long id;
    private ReportType type;
    private String description;
   ...
   ...
}
```

I am looking to turn it into:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "report")
public abstract class Report<E extends Exception> {
    @Id @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "report_type_id")
    private ReportType type;

    @column(name="description")
    private String description;
   ...
   ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class CreditScoreReport<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {

   public void doCreditScoreStuff(){
      ...
   }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
public class DmvReport<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {
   public void doDmvStuff(){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class/5258090#5258090) which already should cover your question.

Comment: @AlexanderBischof - I do not see any examples of multiple concrete implementations saving to the same table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `@Inheritance` instead of `@MappedSuperClass`. Your code would look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "report")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "report_type_id", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Report<E extends Exception> {
    @Id @Column(name="id")
    private long id;

    @column(name="description")
    private String description;
   ...
   ...
}

@Entity(name = "CreditScoreReport")
@DiscriminatorValue("1") // the id corresponding to the credit score report
public class CreditScoreReport<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {

   @Column(name = "specific_credit_score_report_1)
   private Integer specificCreditScoreReport1;

   public void doCreditScoreStuff(){
      ...
   }
}

@Entity(name = "DmvReport")
@DiscriminatorValue("2") // the id corresponding to the DMV report
public class DmvReport<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {

   @Column(name = "specific_dmv_score_report_1)
   private Integer specificDmvScoreReport1;

   public void doDmvStuff(){
      ...
   }
}
```

This strategy allows you to store credit score report and DMV report data in one table (`report`), but instanciate the proper entity according to the `report_value_id` field. You don't have to define the `report_value_id` in your parameters because it was already used to create the required entity.

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes.  Perfect.  Thank you!