# AttributeOverride MappedSuperClass attribute with a different type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Abstract class used as MappedSuperclass like :

```java
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(LogId.class)
public abstract class Log {
    private LocalDateTime moment;
    private String pid;
    // attributes omitted
    private String type;
    private String message;

    @Id
    public LocalDateTime getMoment() { return moment; }
    @Id
    public String getPid() { return pid; }
    // getters/setters omitted
}
```

My `Log` class provides to every entity the same structure with standard attributes `type` and `message`. Each entity represents a table in my database which share every attributes (`@Id` and `// omitted` ones). Columns `type` and `message` might have different names & types.
My first attempt was :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flow_catcher")
public class FlowCatcher extends Log {
    @Override
    @Column(name = "message_type")
    public String getType() {
        return super.getType();
    }

    @Override
    @Column(name = "count")
    @Convert(converter = StringToIntegerDbConverter.class)
    public String getMessage() {
        return super.getMessage();
    }

}
```

Following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5257921/hibernate-how-override-an-attribute-from-mapped-super-class) I used `@AttributeOverride` like :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flow_catcher")
@AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "message_type"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "message", column = @Column(name = "count"))
public class FlowCatcher extends Log {

}
```

But it seems impossible to use any converter to get data `count` as a String and not an Integer.
Here is my error log:

```java
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException:
    Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [count] in table [flow_catcher];
    found [int (Types#INTEGER)], but expecting [varchar(255) (Types#VARCHAR)]
```

**Is there any way to get my column `count` as a `String` and not an `Integer` ?**

*PS: Hibernate `hbm2ddl.auto` is set on `validate` and database scheme can't change.*

---

EDIT 1: I found a working solution but it uses another (unused) column in my database `other_string_column` which doesn't sound clean to me :

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "flow_catcher")
@AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "message_type"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "message", column = @Column(name = "other_string_column"))
public class FlowCatcher extends Log{

    private Integer count;

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        return this.count.toString();
    }

    public Integer getCount() { return count; }
    public void setCount(Integer count) { this.count = count; }
}
```

Comment: Opened a related issue on JPA official Github as it seems impossible to cnvert data type using @MappedSuperClass : https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jpa-api/issues/292

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go with generic

```
@MappedSuperclass
@IdClass(LogId.class)
public class Log<T extends Comparable> implements Serializable {
     @Id
     private LocalDateTime moment;
     @Id
    private String pid;
    //additional required fields here
    
    // Do NOT  SPECIFY MAPPING
    private T message;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "flow_catcher")
@AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "message_type"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "message", column = @Column(name = "count", columnDefinition = "BIGINT(15)"))
public class FlowCatcher extends Log<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3629698185247120860L;
}



@Entity
@Table(name = "flow_catcher_another_sample")
@AttributeOverride(name = "type", column = @Column(name = "message_type"))
@AttributeOverride(name = "message", column = @Column(name = "message", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(20)"))
public class FlowCatcherString extends Log<String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3629698185247120860L;
}
```

Comment: Used your solution with `messageRaw` as a generic object and `message` being transient and generated from messageRaw